# how to get the fetch method to work and the process after linking external data source?

Tags: javascript, json, fetch

i am a beginner at javascript, and i'm asked to build a dynamic image galleries with external data using the fetch() method for an assignment. the requirement for this is to use the fetch() method to link an image slider onto this main page, and i need to make a button to click where a random number is chosen and an external dataset is loaded. but i am having difficulty getting the code to work and i don't know how or where the mistake is, this code is given to me as an example and i need to revise it with my own external links. please help me!

this is what i have in javascript:

```
console.clear();
document.querySelector("button#myLanguageBTN").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function () {
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5); 
    
    switch (randomNumber) {
      case 1:
        var myfetchLink = "https://codepen.io/tchau16/pen/PoaaJYG.js";
      
      case 2:
        var myfetchLink = "https://codepen.io/tchau16/pen/dyKKVGP.js";
        
       case 3:
        var myfetchLink = "https://codepen.io/tchau16/pen/jOKKGWZ.js";
        
        case 4:
        var myfetchLink = "https://codepen.io/tchau16/pen/JjZZrGQ.js";
        
        default:
        var myfetchLink = "https://codepen.io/tchau16/pen/dyKKVGP.js";
    }
    
    console.log(myfetchLink);
    
    .then((response) => {
        return response.text();
      })

    .then((myInformation) => {
        const myReturn = JSON.parse(myInformation);
```

Comment: Your script is missing some characters in the end. });});

Comment: I dont see a fetch in the code

Answer (score 1):

There are few mistakes in your code -

1. switch does not have a break statement, so it was falling to default statement every time.
2. Fetch was not used. Added console logs at appropriate places.
3. use let and const, removed var for myfetchLink.
4. use free apis to test your code.

Switch JS MDN link - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch

Free apis - https://apipheny.io/free-api/#apis-without-key

```js
console.clear();
document.querySelector("button#myLanguageBTN").addEventListener(
  "click",
  function() {
    let randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);
    let myfetchLink = '';
    switch (randomNumber) {
      case 1:
        myfetchLink = "https://www.boredapi.com/api/activity";
        break;
      case 2:
        myfetchLink = "https://catfact.ninja/fact";
        break;
      case 3:
        myfetchLink = "https://api.publicapis.org/entries";
        break;
      case 4:
        myfetchLink = "https://codepen.io/tchau16/pen/JjZZrGQ.js";
        break;
      default:
        myfetchLink = "https://api.coindesk.com/v1/bpi/currentprice.json";
    }
    console.log(myfetchLink);

    fetch(myfetchLink)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        return response.text();
      }).then((myInformation) => {
        console.log(myInformation);
        const myReturn = JSON.parse(myInformation);
      });

  });
```

```html
<button id="myLanguageBTN">Fetch the Data</button>
```

Comment: @jennie-moon Please mark this as answer if it answers your question